# Group results in autocompleted dropdown [Meteor]

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I try to do a dropdown list in my app. First of all I use a Meteor, so that's specific kind of app ofc :)
Second thing is that I use sebdah/meteor-autocompletion package, because I want my results to be sorted in specific way and limited.

The last thing I need is to group my results.
For example: If I have 2 products named "blah" I want to get only 1 "blag" in my dropdown "autocompletion" list.

Some code:

HTML:

```
<template name="InvoicesEditInsertInsertForm">
   <input id="descriptionautocomplete" type="text" name="description" value="" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="New Item...">
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.InvoicesEditInsertInsertForm.rendered = function() {
AutoCompletion.init("input#descriptionautocomplete");
};

Template.InvoicesEditInsertInsertForm.events({
'keyup input#descriptionautocomplete': function () {
        AutoCompletion.autocomplete({
          element: 'input#descriptionautocomplete',       // DOM identifier for the element
          collection: InvoicesItem,              // MeteorJS collection object
          field: 'description',                    // Document field name to search for
          limit: 5,                         // Max number of elements to show
          sort: { modifiedAt: -1 },
            });              // Sort object to filter results with

      },


});
```

I need to use function that could group my "description" here.

I tried to do it in helper and I get it on my screen, but to be honest I don't know how to put that into my dropdown :(

```
  try: function() {
        var item= InvoicesItem.find({},{sort:{modifiedAt:-1}}).fetch();
        var descriptions={};

        _.each(item,function(row){
            var description = row.description;

            if(descriptions[description]==null)
                descriptions[description]={description:description};
        });

        return _.values(descriptions);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want with that package. If you have a look at the [current limitations](https://github.com/sebdah/meteor-autocompletion#current-limitations) of the package documentation, you can see other potential solutions to your problem.

You can do addtional filtering as follows:
`filter: { 'gender': 'female' }});`
but I don't think this will allow you to demand only unique options.

The code you wrote above for `try` won't do anything. Autocomplete doesn't take a field called `try`.

Comment: I understand. I've done "Try" to try (:P) return the collection on my screen in HTML file and that code works - it groups. But I don't want to have it on my screen, just want to have in my "autocomplete dropdown" :)